# How to separate opening and closing tag by conditional template in vue without getting compiling error?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to do some conditional templating where I have to separated the opening and closing tags of some elements. But can't get it to work until they are in the same conditional template tag. As soon as I put the opening tag to one conditional template and the closing tag to another conditional template I get an error. For example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <template v-if="show">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    one
                </li>
        </template>

        // OTHER CONDITIONAL STUFF IN BETWEEN

        <template v-if="show">
                <li>
                    two
                </li>
            </ul>
        </template>
    </div>  
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            show: false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Here I get an error because the opening `<ul>` tag and closing `</ul>` tag are in discrete `<template v-if="..">` tags. I get this error:

```
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) 
  Error compiling template:

    <div>

  <template v-if="show">
      <ul>
          <li>
              one
          </li>
  </template>

  <template v-if="show">
          <li>
              two
          </li>
      </ul>
  </template>

    </div>  

  - tag <ul> has no matching end tag.
```

How can I separate any starting and ending tags inside conditional template tags without breaking the code?

---

### Edited to add the full code

This is the routes that I want to use to generate the menu

```
// routers.js
export let routers = [
{
    name: 'Main Menu 1',
    parent: 0,
}, {
    name: 'Main Menu 2',
    parent: 0
    children: [
        {
            name: 'Menu Item 1-1'
        },{    
            name: 'Menu Item 1-2',
            children: [
                {    
                    name: 'Menu Item 2-1',
                },{    
                    name: 'Menu Item 2-2',
                },{    
                    name: 'Menu Item 2-3',
                    children: [{
                        name: 'SHIT'
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}, {
    name: 'Main Menu 3',
    parent: 0
}
];
```

This is the parent of the recursive component.

```
// left-side.vue
<template>
    <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">
        <section class="sidebar">
            <div id="menu" role="navigation">
                <navigation-cmp :routes="routes"></navigation-cmp>
            </div>
        </section>
    </aside>
</template>

<script>
import navigationCmp from './navigationCmp';

import {routers} from '../../router/routers';

export default {
    name: "left-side",
    computed: {
        routes(){
            return routers;
        }
    },
    components: {
        navigationCmp,
    },
}
</script>
```

This is the recurring part with the problem

```
// navigationCmp.vue
<template>
    <ul class="navigation">

        <template v-for="item in routes">

            <template v-if="item.parent == 0">
                <template v-if="!!item.children">
                    <li class="menu-dropdown">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)"> 
                            <i class="menu-icon ti-check-box"></i> 
                            <span class="mm-text">{{ item.name }}</span> 
                            <span class="fa arrow"></span> 
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                </template>
                <template v-if="!item.children">
                    <router-link to="/" tag="li" exact>
                        <a class="logo"><i class="menu-icon ti-desktop"></i><span class="mm-text">{{ item.name }}</span></a>
                    </router-link>                    
                </template>
            </template>

            <template v-if="!!item.children" v-for="child in item.children" >
                <template v-if="!!child.children">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw ti-receipt"></i> {{ child.name }}
                        <span class="fa arrow"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu form-submenu">
                </template>
                <template v-if="!child.cildren">
                    <router-link tag="li" to="/form-elements" exact>
                        <a class="logo"><i class="menu-icon ti-cup"></i><span class="mm-text"> {{ child.name }} </span></a>
                    </router-link>
                </template>

                <navigation-cmp v-if='!!child.children&&child.children.length>0' :routes='[child]'> </navigation-cmp>

                <template v-if="!!child.children">
                    </ul>
                </template>

            </template>


            <template v-if="!!item.children&&item.parent==0">
                        </ul>
                    </li>
            </template>

        </template>

    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'navigation-cmp',
    props: {
        routes: Array,
    }
}
</script>
```

---

### Full error output

```
main.js:43552 [WDS] Errors while compiling. Reload prevented.
main.js:43558 ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-dfd6e000"}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/layout/navigationCmp.vue
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) 
  Error compiling template:

  <ul class="navigation">

      <template v-if="!item.hidden" v-for="item in routes">

          <template v-if="item.parent == 0">
              <template v-if="show">
                  <li class="menu-dropdown">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)"> 
                          <i class="menu-icon ti-check-box"></i> 
                          <span class="mm-text">{{ item.name }}</span> 
                          <span class="fa arrow"></span> 
                      </a>
                      <!-- <ul class="sub-menu"> -->
              </template>
              <template v-if="!item.children">
                  <router-link to="/" tag="li" exact>
                      <a class="logo"><i class="menu-icon ti-desktop"></i><span class="mm-text">{{ item.name }}</span></a>
                  </router-link>                    
              </template>
          </template>

                  </li>



          <!-- <template v-if="!!item.children&&item.parent == 0"> -->
                      <!-- </ul> -->
          <!-- </template> -->

      </template>

  </ul>

  - tag <li> has no matching end tag.

 @ ./src/components/layout/navigationCmp.vue 5:2-192
 @ ./~/babel-loader/lib?cacheDirectory!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/layout/left-side.vue
 @ ./src/components/layout/left-side.vue
 @ ./~/babel-loader/lib?cacheDirectory!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/layout/layout.vue
 @ ./src/components/layout/layout.vue
 @ ./src/router/routes.js
 @ ./src/router/router.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
errors  @   main.js:43558
sock.onmessage  @   main.js:43801
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js.EventTarget.dispatchEvent @   main.js:22579
(anonymous) @   main.js:23332
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/main.js.SockJS._transportMessage   @   main.js:23330
./node_modules/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js.EventEmitter.emit @   main.js:22483
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage
```

Comment: If the "other conditional stuff" is additional list elements, then you will possibly create invalid HTML because the `ul` element may not be rendered. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I guess you are right @Bert. I am trying to render a recursive menu. But the conditions are the same for both opening and closing tags.

Comment: @Bert (depending on menu item scenario) the opening tags come before the recurring component and the closings come after the recurring part. This is why I need them to be separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I couldn't find out why I get the "*- tag  has no matching end tag*" errors. But there is no doubt that it should work as @RoyJ showed the separating tags with conditional () rendering. **My guess it that when multiple recursions happen, some opening and closing tags are created 
(separated) in different scopes because each recursion starts like a new component. Thus vue can't find the relevant closing tags in the corresponding scope and throws that error.**

My workaround is to don't separate the closing tags from the starting tags. Instead I created an additional component that I place inside the main loop and after I enter that component I close the tags without additional conditional renderings. and the new component handles the remaining recursions. I will go with this one but keep an eye on the problem. Thanks for all help effort.

Here my workaround:

```
// left-side.vue
<template>
    <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">
        <section class="sidebar">
            <div id="menu" role="navigation">
                <navigation-cmp></navigation-cmp>
            </div>
        </section>
    </aside>
</template>

<script>
import navigationCmp from './navigationCmp';

export default {
    name: "left-side",
    components: {
        navigationCmp,
    },
}
</script>
```

I removed the recursion from this part and as I said closed the tags in one single template tag without separating them.

```
// navigationCmp.vue
<template>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <template v-for="route in routes">

            <li v-if="!!route.children" class="menu-dropdown">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <i class="menu-icon ti-check-box"></i>
                    <span class="mm-text">{{ route.name }}</span>
                    <span class="fa arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <navigation-sub :route="route"></navigation-sub>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <router-link v-else to="/" tag="li" exact>
                <a class="logo"><i class="menu-icon ti-desktop"></i><span class="mm-text">{{ route.name }}</span></a>
            </router-link>

        </template>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
import {routers} from '../../router/routers';
import navigationSub from './navigationSub';

export default {
    computed: {
        routes(){
            return routers;
        }
    },
    components: {
        navigationSub
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the new component I told. this is now the recurring part.

```
// navigationSub.vue
<template>
<span>
    <template v-for="child in route.children">
        <li v-if="!!child.children">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                <i class="fa fa-fw ti-receipt"></i> {{ child.name }} 
                <span class="fa arrow"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu form-submenu">
                <navigation-sub :route="child"></navigation-sub>
            </ul>
        </li>
            <a class="logo"><i class="menu-icon ti-cup"></i><span class="mm-text">{{ child.name }}</span></a>
        </router-link>
    </template>
</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'navigation-sub',
    props: ['route']
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This actually works fine for me. Using templates is a recommended way of circumventing the legal-HTML restrictions. Can you make a snippet that exhibits the problem? And say on what platform you're running it, just in case it's platform-dependent?

```js
var spec = {
  template: '#nav-template',
  props: {
    routes: Array,
  }
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    routes: [{
      parent: 0,
      children: 1,
      name: 'first'
    }, {
      parent: 1,
      children: 0,
      name: 'second'
    }]
  },
  components: {
    navigationCmp: spec
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
// navigationCmp.vue
<div id="app">
  <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">
    <section class="sidebar">
      <div id="menu" role="navigation">
        <navigation-cmp :routes="routes"></navigation-cmp>
      </div>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>

<template id="nav-template">
  <ul class=" navigation ">
    <template v-for="item in routes ">

      <template v-if="item.parent==0 ">
        <template v-if="!!item.children ">
          <li class="menu-dropdown ">
            <a href="javascript:void(0) ">
              <i class="menu-icon ti-check-box "></i>
              <span class="mm-text ">{{ item.name }}</span>
              <span class="fa arrow "></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu ">
        </template>
        <template v-if="!item.children ">
          <router-link to="/ " tag="li " exact>
            <a class="logo "><i class="menu-icon ti-desktop "></i><span class="mm-text ">{{ item.name }}</span></a>
          </router-link>
        </template>
      </template>

      <template v-if="!!item.children " v-for="child in item.children ">
        <template v-if="!!child.children ">
          <a href="javascript:void(0) ">
            <i class="fa fa-fw ti-receipt "></i> {{ child.name }}
            <span class="fa arrow "></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="sub-menu form-submenu ">
        </template>
        <template v-if="!child.cildren ">
          <router-link tag="li " to="/form-elements " exact>
            <a class="logo "><i class="menu-icon ti-cup "></i><span class="mm-text "> {{ child.name }} </span></a>
          </router-link>
        </template>

        <navigation-cmp v-if='!!child.children&&child.children.length>0' :routes='[child]'> </navigation-cmp>

        <template v-if="!!child.children ">
          </ul>
        </template>

      </template>


      <template v-if="!!item.children&&item.parent==0 ">
        </ul>
        </li>
      </template>

    </template>

  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: How did you do that :) . I am using vue2 if that is what you mean. I need to digest that first.

Comment: Then I think I must have done something wrong. I will edit and add my whole code @RoyJ.

Comment: I've updated my snippet to use more of your more-complete code. It still runs in a snippet. I may be the build system you're using. I can only guess.

Comment: I am afraid you are right @RoyJ. I have removed all li ul tags except the first one and (edited) added the error output. Does that tell you anything?

Answer (score 0):

As per html standard vue complier will check for proper elements opening and closing tag . In your case opening tag `<ul>` not properly handled.

You can update the your code as folows

```
<template>
    <div>
        <template v-if="show">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    one
                </li>
            </ul>
        </template>

        // OTHER CONDITIONAL STUFF IN BETWEEN

        <template v-if="show">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    two
                </li>
            </ul>
        </template>
    </div>  
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            show: false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: yes but the point is that the opening and closing tags are separated. I need them to open and close in discrete template tags.